# Using a high-end lens on a mid-range camera

Tags: canon

Can I install Canon 1.2 lens on Canon eos 30d instead 5d and expect the same results?

In short, is it advisable to buy expensive lens and put it on medium range camera or both should be of equal stand to arrive at the best results?

Please answer both. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question: No.

I would reccomend reading [this article](http://thewirecutter.com/reviews/the-first-canon-lenses-you-should-buy/) for information on basic lenses and professional ones.

> Because of the difference in sensor size, when you’re using a camera with a smaller sensor than a full-frame one, a given lens’s field of view will be narrower, referred to as the “crop factor.” In camera reviews and manuals, you’ll often see this crop factor given as a multiplier based on the industry standard of a 35 mm, full-frame sensor. The crop factor for Canon APS-C sensors is 1.6—that is, a 50 mm lens on a crop-sensor camera will give you the same field of view as an 80 mm lens will on a full-frame sensor. Other sensor formats have different crop factors; Micro Four Thirds, for example, is 2x. For easy reference, manufacturers give their crop and full-frame lens lines different names: For instance, Canon’s crop-sensor-specific lenses are in the EF-S series, while EF lenses are compatible with all Canon cameras.

TLDR; A lens on a Canon 30d will be 1.6 times more zoomed in then it would be on a 5d.

As to your second question, I would say yes. Despite what many people say, the camera doesn't actually make a big effect on the quality of the image. The lens plays a much more important role in the sharpness and color of the image. The only major problem I can see is that the 30d is quite old, and only has a resolution of 8 megapixels, which is pretty low in today's standards.

Comment: As long as one takes the angle of view into account this is not a reason to not use a higher end lens on a lower tier camera. If I want the angle of view given by a 135mm lens on a FF camera I can use an 85mm lens on an APS-C camera and get the same field of view.

Comment: The first no at the beginning is meant to answer the first question. I realize  now that it makes no sense and will change it. Thank you!